# How to get integer values from text fields in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to create a simple BMI calculator using height and weight and I am having trouble converting my `UITextField` strings to integers for the calculation.

Here's my working code:

```
import UIKit

class BMICalculator: UIViewController {
    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var weightField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var solutionTextField: UILabel!

    @IBAction func calcButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let weightInt = Int(weightField)
        let heightInt = Int(heightField)

        solutionTextField.text = weightInt/(heightInt*heightInt)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? I tried searching for the solution but couldn't find anything specific to this issue.

Comment: You say your code is working. So what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
guard let text1 = weightField.text else {
    return
}

guard let text2 = heightField.text else {
    return
}

guard let weightInt = Int(text1) else {
    return
}

guard let heightInt = Int(text2) else {
    return
}

solutionTextField.text = weightInt /(heightInt*heightInt)
//Change your name for this outlet 'solutionTextField' to 'solutionLabel' since it is a UILabel not UITextField
```

Answer (score 0):

The TextField only accepts a String, it wont take an Int.

Change this:

```
solutionTextField.text = weightInt/(heightInt*heightInt)
```

To this:

```
solutionTextField.text = String(weightInt/(heightInt*heightInt))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is working. To get the values out of your `UITextField`s and convert them to Ints, you'll need to pull them out of the '`.text` properties. Then, when you calculate the result, you'll need to convert it back to a string and set `solutionTextField?.text` equal to that result.

```
class BMICalculator: UIViewController {
    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var weightField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var solutionTextField: UILabel!

    @IBAction func calcButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let weightInt = Int((weightField?.text!)!)
    let heightInt = Int((heightField?.text!)!)

    let solution = weightInt!/(heightInt!*heightInt!)

    solutionTextField?.text = "\(solution)"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this code is very dangerous because you're not safely unwrapping optionals, but that's a different thread.

Hope this helps.